# Why are widgets overlapping in the RelativeLayout which is placed inside a Scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am trying to do the following in an xml layout. My parent Layout is a Relative Layout.

1. I want to make a child Relative Layout scrollable.
2. I have another child Relative Layout and I don't want to make it scrollable.

My xml file is below but the problem is that I whichever new widget(in this case the textview with text taskname) I am adding is getting displayed on the ImageView on the Relative Layout. I am not able to move it. Please guide me.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

 >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"

     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >
         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/propic" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
             android:text="Jack Reacher" />

  <View
     android:id="@+id/View02"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0.3dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Task Name :" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i don't think you can use the scrollview with the relativelayout like that. You should use only scrollview on the outer layout. If you need relativelayout on top of the scrollview, you can use fragment, or maybe change the scrollview with listview. The most important thing is scrollview must be the only outer layout and has only 1 child layout

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should be defined as

1- `<ScrollView>`
2- `<LinearLayout>`
3- `<RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/propic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:text="Jack Reacher" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Task Name :" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```